# Difference between Streaming video format vs Memory Video format

Tags: video, camera, video-streaming

Hi all,
What is exact Difference between Streaming video format vs Memory Video format

Streaming Video Format Support: RGB, YUV 4:2:2, YUV 4:4:4, YUV 4:2:0
Memory Video Format Support: RGB8, BGRX8, RGBX8, YUYV8, YUVX8, RGBX10, YUVX10, Y_UV8, Y_UV8_420, UYVY8, YUV8, Y_UV10, Y_UV10_420, Y8, Y10

Any input will be of great help

Answer (score 1):

These are all image formats that describe how color information is stored, in stream or in memory. Hardware may use specific layouts that allow for optimized memory access.

The layouts depend on:

- [color space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_space): examples include [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_space) (red, green, blue), [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) (luma + chrominance)
- [downsampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_subsampling) scheme: taking advantage of the human visual system's acuity for color differences vs. luminance to reduce data size

The image data can be represented in different [formats](https://wiki.videolan.org/YUV):

- packed: one plane for all the values
- planar: one plane for each color component
- semi-planar: only two planes

Examples:

- Planar formats:

[image: Planar formats]

- Bi-planar formats:
  [image]

Image source and further reading: [Pixel and Planar Image Formats](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/ipp-dev-reference/top/volume-2-image-processing/image-color-conversion/pixel-and-planar-image-formats.html)

Comment: Thanks for the detail description.

Comment: I also did some research and if i am not wrong out of many reason one reason for having different formats, may be that if  store  streaming  data directly in memory  from programming perspective ,it  can increase our computational stuff .For eg if we have RGB888 streaming data then we need a 24bit data type or do two 16bit read or one 32 bit read and discard 8bit ,so better add 8bit to it RGBX and access it using unsigned int.